# Twilio Studio Outgoing Calls

Tags: twilio, twilio-studio

I am working with Twilio Studio to make outgoing calls but once the caller picks there is a message stating there's an application error. We're trying to play a recording when the user picks up the phone but it only makes it calling the user then says the application error. Is there anything we're missing between the outgoing call widget and the play message widget?

Comment: Please, clarify your question. What type of error are you getting exactly? Can you show the specific portion of code where this error is raised? Also, try to clarify your expectations.

Comment: Is the URL of audio file and the format okay? Can you play it in a browser? If you change it to say message, does it work? Do you have any errors in the debug console?

Comment: When we run our test and the user picks up the phone it the automated voice says application error. When we go into the debugger in Twilio Studio we get an HTTP retrieval error or an outbound HTTP request failed. We also tried changing it to just say a message and we get the same errors

Comment: Try a different mp3 file, maybe the encoding in your mp3 is not supported by Twilio. For example, https://demo.twilio.com/docs/classic.mp3.

Comment: When we are trying to play a message it is a recording done in Twilio, the recording is taken from a widget in Twilio Studio.